# How to use unicode in haxe?

Tags: haxe

How to use unicode characters in haxe 3?

I tried this example:

```
trace("Haxe is great :)"+"\u0600");
```

But, it will not work, I get this error:

```
character 29 : Invalid escape sequence
```

So, how would I add unicode strings?
Here is where to try it: http://try.haxe.org/#be311

Comment: Try look into http://haxe.org/com/libs/hxunicode ?

Comment: I saw it, but isn't there a direct way in haxe3?

Comment: I'm not sure.. maybe wait for some answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to just use the character itself:

`trace("Haxe is great :) ␆" );`

But whether or not that's feasible depends on your usage.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just paste the unicode character? It seems to work for me

Look at this http://try.haxe.org/#38E77

edit: relevant code in case try.haxe stops working:

```
trace("Haxe is great :)"+"本");
```